# Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 when client not on NT Domain

Tags: dns, office-communicator

I'm trying to run Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 on client which is not part of an NT Domain, but which has VPN access to my corporate network.  When trying to authenticate, however, MOC just hangs forever.  Is there some way to configure MOC so that it connects, even if the client machine is not a member of the NT Domain?

I have verified that a corporate machine can connect from the same remote location, so it's not a networking issue.

Comment: This isn't development related - you might have more luck on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Thank you - I actually figured it out after a bit more digging: you need to have the domain's certificate installed as a Trusted Root on the client machine.  So, it's doable: you just need to really really trust the server if it's a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score -1):

I figured this out: you need to have the domain's certificate installed as a Trusted Root on the client machine. So, it's doable: you just need to really really trust the server if it's a self-signed certificate.